# Django 1.9 JSONField order_by

Tags: python, django, django-1.9, django-jsonfield

I have the following django model that contains JSONField:

```
class RatebookDataEntry(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(blank=True, default=[])
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ratebook data entries'
```

And **data** field contains this json:

```
{
    "annual_mileage": 15000, 
    "description": "LEON DIESEL SPORT COUPE", 
    "body_style": "Coupe", 
    "range_name": "LEON", 
    "co2_gkm_max": 122, 
    "manufacturer_name": "SEAT"
}
```

Can I sort queryset by one of the data fields? This query doesn't work.

```
RatebookDataEntry.objects.all().order_by("data__manufacturer_name")
```

Comment: Not that I know of (on a queryset), but this kind of indicates to me that you might actually need an object model for "data" instead of json

Comment: As an aside, use `default=list` instead of `default=[]`, otherwise you'll end up with the same list shared between different instances.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As Julien mentioned ordering on `JSONField` is not yet supported in Django. But it's possible via [`RawSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#raw-sql-expressions) using [PostgreSQL functions for jsonb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html). In OP's case:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL
RatebookDataEntry.objects.all().order_by(RawSQL("data->>%s", ("manufacturer_name",)))
```

Comment: And in case you want DESC ordering, you can introduce annotated field and order by it. Like this: RatebookDataEntry.objects.annotate(manufacturer_name=RawSQL("data->>%s", ("manufacturer_name",)).order_by("-manufacturer_name")

Comment: Just in case anyone is only looking at the accepted answer, this is a feature in Django 2.1, see my answer for links.

Comment: This doesn't work for MySQL though, any work around for MySQL?

Comment: Use `->` instead of `->>` if you want to order numeric values. (`->>` [gets JSON object field as text](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING))

Answer (score 17):

Since Django 1.11, [`django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb.KeyTextTransform`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/contrib/postgres/fields/jsonb.py#L115) can be used instead of `RawSQL`

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTextTransform

qs = RatebookEntry.objects.all()
qs = qs.annotate(manufacturer_name=KeyTextTransform('manufacturer_name', 'data'))
qs = qs.order_by('manufacturer_name')
# or...
qs = qs.order_by('-manufacturer_name')
```

On Django 1.10, you'll have to subclass `KeyTransform` yourself:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTransform

class KeyTextTransform(KeyTransform):
    operator = '->>'
    nested_operator = '#>>'
    _output_field = TextField()
```

Note: the difference between `KeyTransform` and `KeyTextTransform` is that `KeyTransform` will return the JSON representation of the object, whereas `KeyTextTransform` will return the value of the object.

For example, if `data` is `{"test": "stuff"}`, `KeyTextTransform` will return `'stuff'`, whereas `KeyTransform` will return `'"stuff"'` (which can be parsed by `json.loads`)

Comment: def what I needed

Comment: this should be the preferred answer

Comment: My json field has data in below format, how can I use it to sort based on first ip address in the dictionary?

<QuerySet [{'ip_addresses': {'172.19.128.1': 1, '192.168.0.129': 1}}, {'ip_addresses': {'10.248.91.72': 1, '10.248.91.73': 1, '10.248.91.74': 1}}, {'ip_addresses': {'1.1.34.13': 1}}]>

Answer (score 16):

This question (and most of the answers) are for Django 1.9. However, **Django versions 3.1 and newer** support `JSONField` [on recent versions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField) of MariaDB, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, and SQLite.

The behavior around creating/maintaining indexes on JSON fields may vary across database engines, but ordering should work with the exact syntax you have in your question:

```py
RatebookDataEntry.objects.all().order_by("data__manufacturer_name")
```

Note that unless you do further filtering, this will include database rows where the `manufacturer_name` key in the `data` JSONField does not exist.

Answer (score 10):

Following [Daniil Ryzhkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1241619/daniil-ryzhkov) answer and [Eugene Prikazchikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477280/eugene-prikazchikov) comment, you should be able to sort ASC and DESC on JSON data fields without annotating your queryset, by using both `RawSQL` and `OrderBy`. Also, you can perform case insensitive sorting by adding `LOWER`:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL, OrderBy

RatebookDataEntry.objects.all().order_by(OrderBy(RawSQL("LOWER(data->>%s)", ("manufacturer_name",)), descending=True))
```

To compare integers fields, you can cast as integer:

```
RatebookDataEntry.objects.all().order_by(OrderBy(RawSQL("cast(data->>%s as integer)", ("annual_mileage",)), descending=True))
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an upcoming feature which has already been added and will be released in Django 2.1, expected release of August 2018.

See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24747 and https://github.com/django/django/pull/8528 for details.

Comment: see  for example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

Answer (score 3):

The documentation does not mention this possibility. It seems you cannot use order_by based on a JSONfield for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following to order by date (using `to_date`). Assuming there's another value in `data` called `created_date` (e.g. 03.06.2019).

```
RatebookDataEntry.objects.all().order_by(
        OrderBy(
            RawSQL("to_date(values->>%s, 'DD.MM.YYYY')", ("created_date",)),
            descending=True,
        )
    )
```