# Django ordering by JSONField key

Tags: django, sql-order-by, django-jsonfield

I have the following django model with a JSONField:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(default={})
```

And data field with struct bellow:

```
{
    "a": 1, 
    "b": 2, 
}
```

How ordering queryset by one of the data fields?

```
TestModel.objects.all().order_by("data__a") # error
```

Comment: Short answer: you can't do this.
See details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641759/django-1-9-jsonfield-order-by

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django 1.9 JSONField order\_by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641759/django-1-9-jsonfield-order-by)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is this is being tracked as a new feature now https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24747.

Looks like it'll land in Django 2.1, expected August 2018.