# Django order_by on a nested json field

Tags: python, sql, json, django, django-queryset

My models are something like this.

```
class Foo():
    bar = models.ForeignKey('Bar', related_name='bar')
    payload = JSONField()

class Bar():
    candy = models.ForeignKey('Candy', related_name='candy')

class Candy():
    payload = JSONField()
```

My queryset looks something like this

```
# I want to order by a name on the json field
queryset = [
{
  "id": 1,
  "payload": {"age": 10, "company": "ccc"}
  "bar": 
   {
     'id': 1,
      "candy":
       {
        "payload": 
           {
           "names": ["text":"abc", "tag":"foo"], ["text":"abb", "tag":"bar"]
           }
       }
   }
 }, 
 {
  "id": 2,
  "payload": {"age": 12, "company": "aa"}
  "bar": 
   {
     'id': 2,
      "candy":
       {
        "payload": 
           {
           "names": ["text":"aaa", "tag":"bar"], ["text":"bbb", "tag":"bart"]
           }
       }
   }
 }]


foo = Foo.objects.all() #now I want to order foo by "names.text"
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
foo = foo.order_by(RawSQL("payload->>%s", ("age",))) #this works!!
foo = foo.order_by(RawSQL("bar.candy.payload->>%s", ("names[0].text",))) #does not work
```

The second statement does not work. I got inspiration to use `RawSQL` from here 
[Django 1.9 JSONField order_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641759/django-1-9-jsonfield-order-by)

I cannot figure out how to navigate to that particular class and then execute the query. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

if you use RawSQL entered content must be sql query. the entered query only select Foo models objects.

first you must select related models content.

```
foo = Foo.objects.select_related("bar__candy")
```

in python shell if you enter

```
print foo.query
```

you can see database query entered and all fields names

after that you must enter RawSQL with selected entered field name.

if you see in query all fields names are in format

```
"<table name>"."<field name>"
```

if your app name is **Main** your candy table name in database is **main_candy** so you can enter RawSQL:

```
foo = foo.order_by(RawSQL("main_candy.payload->>%s", ("names[0].text",)))
```

and it must work.