# Django order_by on a nested JSONField

Tags: json, django, postgresql

I have `JSONField` on my `Product` model and in this model, I have nested fields.

For example:

```
"data": {
    'products':{
            "name": "ProductA", 
            "color": "Brown", 
            "price": {
                "end_user": 54,
                "credit_cart": 60
            },
            "name": "ProductB", 
            "color": "Red", 
            "price": {
                "end_user": 100,
                "credit_cart":120
             },

     }
}
```

I want to order nested `end_user` field.

this is my attempt:

```
Products.objects.order_by(RawSQL("data->>%s", ("data__price__end_user",)))
```

I found the answer:

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(
                end_user=RawSQL("data->'products'->'price'->'->'end_user'", [])
            ).order_by('end_user')
```

Comment: What database backend are you using? In what context do you need to order this object?  Please add more specifics and what your desired outcome would be.

Comment: @Jane I'm using ```PostgreSQL```. I have products and products have more than one price. I want to order ```end_user``` field. I want to get ```desc``` order. 
I've already try ```Products.objects.order_by(RawSQL("data->>%s", ("data__price__end_user",)))```

Comment: please don't post code in comments.  What server-side language are you using?

Comment: I went ahead and edited your question with the information you gave me.  You should always update your question with new information.

Comment: Topic title is Django order_by on a nested JSONField. What do you expect? Python obviously.

Comment: sorry just realized that.  I'm tired xD

Comment: what is wrong with your attempt?  Is the order wrong, do you get null results? etc.

Comment: No. I get products in unexcepted order. Not ASC.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is possible since Django 1.11 using KeyTextTransform

Django => 1.11

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTextTransform

qs = RatebookEntry.objects.all()
qs = qs.annotate(manufacturer_name=KeyTextTransform('manufacturer_name', 'data'))
qs = qs.order_by('manufacturer_name')
# or...
qs = qs.order_by('-manufacturer_name')
```

Django < 1.11

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTransform

class KeyTextTransform(KeyTransform):
    operator = '->>'
    nested_operator = '#>>'
    _output_field = TextField()
```

> Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50046631/3345051
>
> New Implementation (2.1): https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24747

Comment: In this problem, the user has one JSONField but I have nested JSONField. For example, manufacturer has 2 or more ```manufacturer_name``` name. In my issue, I want to order by ```end_user``` DESC or ASC.

Answer (score 0):

Is this work?

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL
RatebookDataEntry.objects.all().order_by(RawSQL("data->>%s", ("data__products__price__end_user",)))
```

Or how about this:

```
entries = RatebookDataEntry.objects.all()
ordered_entries = sorted(entries, key=lambda x: x['data']['products']['price']['end_user'])
```

Comment: For first one answer is no. And for the second one, I did not try because I don't want to sort with Python. I want to sort in the database side.