# DjangoRestFramework: search and sort a element inside a JsonField

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible somehow to search/sort a field inside a JsonField by creating a custom method using django_rest_framework?

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| name      |               my_json_field                      |
---------------------------------------------------------------- 
| record_1  | {"field1": "A1", "field2": "A2", "field3": "A3"} | 
----------------------------------------------------------------
| record_2  | {"field1": "B2", "field2": "B1" }                |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| record_3  | {"field1": "C3", "field2": "C2", "field3": "C1"} |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

So that:

- if filter by my_json_field -> field1 = "A1" I get:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| name      |               my_json_field                      |
---------------------------------------------------------------- 
| record_1  | {"field1": "A1", "field2": "A2", "field3": "A3"} | 
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

- if sort DESC by my_json_field -> field3 I get:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| name      |               my_json_field                      |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| record_3  | {"field1": "C3", "field2": "C2", "field3": "C1"} |
---------------------------------------------------------------- 
| record_1  | {"field1": "A1", "field2": "A2", "field3": "A3"} | 
----------------------------------------------------------------
| record_2  | {"field1": "B2", "field2": "B1" }                |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but hopefully should point you in the right direction.

The first question is what Django can do - can Django filter and sort by arbitrary key transforms on `JSONField`s? For filtering, [absolutely](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield). For sorting, not directly. Generally, you can't sort by transforms, however you can annotate those transforms to the queryset, then filter on the annotations. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50046631/1103124) provides an example of how to do this with a `JSONField`.

The second question is what can DRF do. Looking through the code, the `SearchFilter` does not heavily rely on the model meta, so using a key transform in `search_fields` should be fine. If not, you might try the annotation instead. Similar to Django, the `OrderingFilter` doesn't support transforms, but it does support annotations. Putting this together, something like the following should work:

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets, filters
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTextTransform
from my_app.models import MyModel

class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects \
        .annotate(field1=KeyTextTransform('my_json_field', 'field1') \
        .annotate(field2=KeyTextTransform('my_json_field', 'field2') \
        .annotate(field3=KeyTextTransform('my_json_field', 'field3')

    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, filters.OrderingFilter]
    search_fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']
    ordering_fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']
```

Note that you can't explicitly search by just a single field, all search fields are searched. To do that, you'd need to use something like `django-filter`.

Comment: Thank you very much I was able to do what I wanted! I didn't know annotation before today

Comment: Since Django 3 use django.db.models.fields.json.KeyTextTransform